# Having trouble following the behaviour of nested for loops

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using Python3.5 and have an SQLite database which is populated with data which I am selecting and performing calculations with. The code I am using is below.

```
def Horizontal_Cyl ():
c.execute("SELECT DIR_Dish1 FROM Tanks")  
DIR_Dish1 = c.fetchall()  
print ("Dish ",DIR_Dish1)  
c.execute("SELECT DIR_Radius FROM Tanks")
DIR_Radius = c.fetchall()
print ("Radius",DIR_Radius)
c.execute("SELECT VAR_LevelReg FROM Tanks")
VAR_LevelReg = c.fetchall()
print ("Level",VAR_LevelReg)
c.execute("SELECT DIR_Length FROM Tanks")
DIR_Length = c.fetchall()
print ("Length",DIR_Length)
x = Dish_Vol()  
dish1Volume = x 
for row in c.execute("SELECT DIR_Radius, VAR_LevelReg, DIR_Length FROM Tanks"):
    for DIR_Radius in row:
        for VAR_LevelReg in row:
            for DIR_Length in row:
                cylinderVolume = ((( DIR_Radius * DIR_Radius) * math.acos((DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg ) / DIR_Radius)) - \
                ((DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg) * math.sqrt((DIR_Radius * DIR_Radius) - \
                ((DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg) * (DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg))))) * (DIR_Length / 1000)

                volume = cylinderVolume / 1000

                Total = volume + dish1Volume + dish1Volume
                print ("Total: ",Total)
```

Where Dish_Vol is another piece of code which gives me a number, x, to be used later.

Where I am having trouble is here:

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT DIR_Radius, VAR_LevelReg, DIR_Length FROM Tanks"):
    for DIR_Radius in row:
        for VAR_LevelReg in row:
            for DIR_Length in row:
                cylinderVolume = ((( DIR_Radius * DIR_Radius) * math.acos((DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg ) / DIR_Radius)) - \
                ((DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg) * math.sqrt((DIR_Radius * DIR_Radius) - \
                ((DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg) * (DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg))))) * (DIR_Length / 1000)

                volume = cylinderVolume / 1000

                Total = volume + dish1Volume + dish1Volume
                print ("Total: ",Total)
```

for Total, I am getting the output:

```
Total:  4664.471999862134
Total:  5045.348779887742
Total:  27614.512396288894
Total:  5148.702861581893
Total:  5575.141845226646
Total:  30844.130922594857
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TJgro\workspace\SQLite Practise\Dish_Vol\Calculations    \__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
main()
  File "C:\Users\TJgro\workspace\SQLite Practise\Dish_Vol\Calculations\__init__.py", line 202, in main
Horizontal_Cyl ()
  File "C:\Users\TJgro\workspace\SQLite Practise\Dish_Vol\Calculations\__init__.py", line 190, in Horizontal_Cyl
cylinderVolume = ((( DIR_Radius * DIR_Radius) * math.acos((DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg ) / DIR_Radius)) - \
ValueError: math domain error
```

The final total listed before the error; 30,844.... is the correct result I am looking for. And the math domain error I am postulating is due to somewhere there being a negative output from the iterations im performing interacting with the trigonometry.

What I can't seem to grasp though, is how the for loops are behaving, I can't seem to follow them and arrive at the numbers im geting as output. In 
previous parts of the program, I have written for example:

```
  for row in c.execute("SELECT DIR_Dish1 FROM Tanks"):  #Main loop
    for DIR_Dish1 in row:                             #Select the column DIR_Dish1 for each entry
        if DIR_Dish1 > 0.001:
```

And this has let me achieve the task as the calculations only involved the variable DIR_Dish1. The probelm im facing now, is that the calculations I need to perform, involve multiplying say DIR_Dish1, by VAR_LevelReg, 
so I would write something akin to:

```
 for row in c.execute("SELECT DIR_Radius, VAR_LevelReg, DIR_Length FROM Tanks"):
    for DIR_Radius, VAR_LevelReg, DIR_Length in row:
```

but this throws an int type is not iterable error.

Any help would be appreciated, as to how i can arrive at just the value 30,844... being outputted using for loops. Thank you.

Comment: What are the values involved in the computation when the error is thrown?

Comment: DIR_Radius =1371
VAR_LevelReg = 1500
DIR_Length = 9144
Dish1 = 180
x = 308.27451

Comment: And does the formular to calcualte `cylinderVolume` from these values work? Did you try to execute the formular only using these values?

Comment: Yeah the formula is tested and verified working. The trouble i'm having is when there are multiple rows in the databse. The parameters are different for different systems, so these numbers aren't static. Hence i need to iterate through the rows selecting the variables and performing the calculation to produce Total for each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT DIR_Radius FROM Tanks"):
    for DIR_Radius in row:
        R2 = DIR_Radius**2
        for row in c.execute("SELECT VAR_LevelReg FROM Tanks"):
            for VAR_LevelReg in row:
                RL = DIR_Radius - VAR_LevelReg
                for row in c.execute("SELECT DIR_Length FROM Tanks"):
                    for DIR_Length in row:
                        cylinderVolume = ((( R2) * math.acos((RL ) / DIR_Radius)) - \
                        ((RL) * math.sqrt((R2) - ((RL**2))))) * (DIR_Length / 1000)
print("cyclinder Volume = ", cylinderVolume)

volume = cylinderVolume / 1000
print("Volume = ", volume)
Total = volume + dish1Volume + dish1Volume
print ("Total: ",Total)
```

This does what I wanted, the output:

```
cyclinder Volume =  30227581.910446744
Volume =  30227.581910446745
Total:  30844.130922594857
```

Obviously the problem is with the indentation syntax in python, the program is iterating through the for loops numerous times due to the bad indentation in the source code.